# Why it grab letter by letter instead of full string ruby on rails + javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

so i have to following script

```
var item = '<%= @invoice.items.length %>'
  var items_arr = '<%= raw @invoice.items.to_json %>' /* items_arr = ["kostas","spoom","fork"]*/
  var table = document.getElementById("tableid");
  for (var i = 1; i < item; i++)
    {
    console.log(items_arr)
    console.log(items_arr[1])
            var rowid=table.rows.length-1;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowid+1);
            row.id = (rowid+1).toString();
            var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
        cell0.innerHTML = items_arr[i];
        cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='number'  size='8' name='invoice[tax][i]' step='0.01'></input>";
        cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='number'  size='8' name='invoice[discount][i]' step='0.01'></input>";
        cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='number'  size='8' name='invoice[sum][i]' step='0.01'></input>";
        cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='number'  size='8' name='invoice[price][i]' step='0.01' ></input>";

    }
```

[image: javascript console]

so my array is items = ["kostas","spoom","fork"]
so when i do items[0] i want to grab "kostas" but for some reason items[0] grab ***"***

also in ruby on rails @invoice.items[0] == "kostas"

Comment: This isn't gonna work: `var items_arr = '<%= raw @invoice.items.to_json %>'`. You have to parse the JSON when you load it into JS, use `JSON.parse` on the string. Also, learn to use `debugger` in the browser dev tools, it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: worked fine thanks!